# ValueError: labels ['timestamp'] not contained in axis

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, data-science

I am learning machine learning and I came across this [code](https://github.com/azabet/Machine-Learning).
I am trying to run the file `"Recommender-Systems.py"` from the above source. But it throws an error 
`ValueError: labels ['timestamp'] not contained in axis.`
 How can it be removed?

Here's a dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4cksq4dwgbaqd07/u.data?dl=0) of `u.data` file.

Comment: do you have the `u.data` file? can you provide a sample of it?

Comment: I have downloaded the data set from [here](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is missing the headers so it's being wrongly inferred by the first row.

You need to change a little bit the `Recommender-Systems.py` and manually inform the headers.

The right header is available in the `README` file from your data set.

Change your file to something like this:

```
## Explore the data (line 27)
data = pd.read_table('u.data', header=None)  # header=None avoid getting the columns automatically
data.columns = ['userID', 'itemID',
                'rating', 'timestamp']       # Manually set the columns.
data = data.drop('timestamp', axis=1)        # Continue with regular work.

...

## Load user information (line 75)
users_info = pd.read_table('u.user', sep='|', header=None)
users_info.columns = ['useID', 'age', 'gender',
                      'occupation' 'zipcode']
users_info = users_info.set_index('userID')

...

## Load movie information (line 88)
movies_info = pd.read_table('u.item', sep='|', header=None)
movies_info.columns = ['movieID', 'movie title', 'release date',
                       'video release date', 'IMDb URL', 'unknown',
                       'Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation', "Children's",
                       'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Documentary', 'Drama',
                       'Fantasy', 'Film-Noir', 'Horror', 'Musical',
                       'Mystery', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi',' Thriller',
                       'War', 'Western']
movies_info = movies_info.set_index('movieID')#.drop(low_count_movies)
```

This should work (but I'm not sure if I got all the right names for the columns).