# "ValueError: labels ['timestamp'] not contained in axis" error

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, data-science

I have this code ,i want to remove the column 'timestamp' from the file :[u.data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4cksq4dwgbaqd07/u.data?dl=0) but can't.It shows the error
"ValueError: labels ['timestamp'] not contained in axis"
How can i correct it

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rc("font", size=14)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split



data = pd.read_table('u.data')
data.columns=['userID', 'itemID','rating', 'timestamp']
data.drop('timestamp', axis=1)


N = len(data)
print data.shape
print list(data.columns)
print data.head(10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: labels \['timestamp'\] not contained in axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763715/valueerror-labels-timestamp-not-contained-in-axis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the biggest problem that one faces and that undergoes unnoticed is that in the u.data file while inserting headers the separation should be exactly the same as the separation between a row of data. For example if a tab is used to separate a tuple then you should not use spaces.
 In your u.data file add headers and separate them exactly with as many whitespaces as were used between the items of a row.
PS: Use sublime text, notepad/notepad++ does not work sometimes.

Comment: wow..that really solved the problem.can't believe it was so simple

Answer (score 2):

> "ValueError: labels ['timestamp'] not contained in axis"

You don't have headers in the file, so the way you loaded it you got a `df` where the column names are the first rows of the data. You tried to access colunm `timestamp` which doesn't exist.

**Your `u.data` doesn't have headers in it**

```
$head u.data                   
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
```

So working with column names isn't going to be possible unless add the headers. You can add the headers to the file `u.data`, e.g. I opened it in a text editor and added the line `a   b   c   timestamp` at the top of it (this seems to be a tab-separated file, so be careful when added the header not to use spaces, else it breaks the format)

```
$head u.data                   
a   b   c   timestamp
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
```

Now your code works and `data.columns` returns

```
Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'timestamp'], dtype='object')
```

And the rest of the trace of your working code is now

```
(100000, 4) # the shape
['a', 'b', 'c', 'timestamp'] # the columns
     a    b  c  timestamp # the df
0  196  242  3  881250949
1  186  302  3  891717742
2   22  377  1  878887116
3  244   51  2  880606923
4  166  346  1  886397596
5  298  474  4  884182806
6  115  265  2  881171488
7  253  465  5  891628467
8  305  451  3  886324817
9    6   86  3  883603013
```

**If you don't want to add headers**

Or you can drop the column 'timestamp' using it's index (presumably 3), we can do this using `df.ix` below it selects all rows, columns index 0 to index 2, thus dropping the column with index 3

```
data.ix[:, 0:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it this way:

```
data = pd.read_table('u.data', header=None,
                     names=['userID', 'itemID','rating', 'timestamp'],
                     usecols=['userID', 'itemID','rating']
)
```

Check:

```
In [589]: data.head()
Out[589]:
   userID  itemID  rating
0     196     242       3
1     186     302       3
2      22     377       1
3     244      51       2
4     166     346       1
```

Comment: Yeah no need to load it if we're never going to use it

Comment: @bakkal, totally agree with you :)